# Control how “Finish” URL is openened - DocuSign in an iframe

Tags: iframe, docusignapi

I am displaying a DocuSign powerform inside a Salesforce Community page.  When the user clicks “Finish” on the DocuSign form, I want the finish URL (which I’ve configured in the DocuSign settings) to open in the parent window - NOT inside the iframe.

I’ve seen suggestions that I might add the  tag with target = _parent to my iframe HTML, but I’ve tried this a couple of different ways without success.  Has anyone done this, and if so - exactly how should the syntax look?  Or - perhaps there’s a way to put JavaScript into the DocuSign URL field?

I’m hoping I don’t need to do something more complex than an iframe (I.e., embedded signing) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

The page you currently redirect to, add Javascript like this:

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
```

The .top part here, means the parent iframe, and then you can switch it to whatever page you want.