# How to redirect out of the Iframe after Docusign Signin Process Finished

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, docusignapi

I would want to redirect the users to another part of my website once they've finished signing on the Docusign Iframe but I am having trouble getting out of the Iframe.
I know this question has already been asked here, but without answer : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54259287/control-how-finish-url-is-openened-docusign-in-an-iframe)

And [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951027/breaking-out-of-iframe-in-docusign) but the code the user provided doesn't work in my case, the new page doesn't even load :

```
<iframe id ="docusignFrame" name="docusignFrame" th:src="${docusignURL}" width="100%" height="900" onLoad="(this.contentWindow.location != '' ? DocusignCompleted(this.contentWindow.location) : void(0));"></iframe>
<script>
function DocusignCompleted(url) {
    $("#docusignFrame").hide();
}
</script>
```

What I have tried :

PHP code :

```
$recipientViewRequest = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest([
    'authentication_method' => $authenticationMethod, 'client_user_id' => $clientUserId,
    'recipient_id' => '1', 'return_url' => $baseUrl . '/' . "end_print.php",
    'user_name' => $signerName, 'email' => $signerEmail
]);
$results = $envelopeApi->createRecipientView($accountId, $envelopeId,
    $recipientViewRequest);
return $results['url'];
```

HTML code :

```
<iframe src="<?=$result?>" width="1000" height="1000"></iframe>
```

Is this possible, only using `HTML` and `PHP` or do I have to try something in `JavaScript` like the user on top.

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution in my case, it is to check the `onload` of the Iframe and then in `Javascript` to check that the `GET["event"]` of Docusign is exists.

In this case, if the signing process fails it will still change page, but you can change this part of the code to what event you want.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function handleIframe(str){
                url = new String(str);
                if (url.indexOf('?event=signing_complete') > 0) {
                    window.top.location.href = "signing_complete.php";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="1000"
                height="1000"
                onload="handleIframe(this.contentWindow.location)"
                frameborder="0"
                src="<?=$result?>">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm working on a fix of the following error at the moment, if found I'll also post it here.

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a > cross-origin frame.
>      at new String ()
>     at handleIframe [...]
>      at HTMLIFrameElement.onload [...]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not using an iFrame for the signing ceremony:

1. iFrames, unless they use up 100% of the height and width of the screen, will mess up signing on mobile devices. (Tip: people *love* to sign on mobile devices.)
2. iFrames are not needed for maintaining your app's state: use your framework's session library for that.
3. The iFrame makes it more difficult to work with DocuSign (as you've experienced).

Conclusion: it's better and easier to simply redirect to the DocuSign Signing Ceremony. DocuSign will redirect the signer's browser back to you when they're done.

### Added

#### Re: framework's session library

A session library enables your app to easily maintain state for a particular use throughout their session.

Eg, for PHP see https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

#### Re: iFrames not recommended:

See DocuSign docs [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient):

> Note: Please redirect the client to the URL. iFrames should not be used, especially if the recipient is using a mobile or tablet.

Also, see the eg-03 series of examples for multiple languages. They all redirect the browser. See the [list of repos.](https://github.com/docusign?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=eg-03&type=&language=)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment on the usage of Iframe's with Docusign, could you explain what you mean by _use your framework's session library for that._ I am new to API's.

Comment: could you link me where it explains how to do what you said in the Docusign Documentation

Comment: You don't recommand the Iframe which I can understand but in a few places in the docusign docs, embedded signature is explained with only Iframes like https://github.com/docusign/docusign-soap-sdk/wiki/Code-Walkthrough-_-Embedded-Signing

Comment: Sigh, our soap docs are very old. We continue to support soap, but the documentation is not being updated very much.